# How to convert asynchronous stream of JPEG images to video stream

Tags: conversion, mpeg

I have an HTTP server that streams images from a camera in a series of HTTP responses to a single request. The frame rate of this direct stream fluctuates, ie. some frames take longer to produce, some take shorter. The average framerate is around 2.1 FPS.

I can open the stream directly from the server with gstreamer this way:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.1.225:81/stream ! queue ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I want to augment this pipeline to convert the image stream to a MPEG TS. I guess a part of my problem is to convert the asynchronous images from the original source to a constant frame rate for the resulting MPEG TS. But as soon as I add the mpeg2enc plugin to the pipeline I get this error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:souphttpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:souphttpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../plugins/elements/gstqueue.c(990): gst_queue_handle_sink_event (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Any ideas how to address this? I guess I need a "sample-and-hold" plugin that just feeds the most recent image to the mpeg2enc plugin at the rate it requires, and maybe other stuff as well.